# hide slider carousel button when there are no more elements with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Good morning!!

I need to block the arrow on the left or hide the date and only use the right if there elements. One time you use the right arrow "because there were more hidden elements" and this has no more elements desahibilitarla not slide to keep doing the right arrow. The left arrow to return to the top dwell. As is possible with bootstrap or javascript? Please help!!! :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHFy5.png)

```
       <%
    // final List<String> articlesMarkup = ContentListWebContexts.getArticlesMarkup(renderRequest);
    final List<String> articlesMarkupPrestatges = ContentListWebContexts.getArticlesMarkup(renderRequest);

    final ContentListPreferences prefs = ContentListWebContexts.getContentListPrefs(renderRequest);

    final String viewAllFullFriendlyUrl = prefs.getViewAllPageFullUrl(themeDisplay);

    // pageContext.setAttribute( "articlesMarkup", articlesMarkup );
    pageContext.setAttribute( "articlesMarkupPrestatges", articlesMarkupPrestatges );
    pageContext.setAttribute( "viewAllFullFriendlyUrl", viewAllFullFriendlyUrl);
    %>

    <%-- Vista, propiamente dicha --%>

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty articlesMarkupPrestatges}">
            <p><liferay-ui:message key="contentlist.view.noarticles" /></p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <%
    //          String friendlyURL = themeDisplay.getLayout().getFriendlyURL();
    //          String currentUrl = URLDecoder.decode(themeDisplay.getURLCurrent(),"UTF-8");
    //          String homeUrl = themeDisplay.getURLHome();
    //          int startIndex = 1;
            %>

            <div class="seccionTitular margenSup">
                <h1 class="two">
    <!--            <div class="masInfoTitular"></div> -->
                <span><liferay-ui:message key="contentlist.view.title.prestatges" /></span>
                <div class="rayaTitularPrestatges pull-left"></div>
                <div class="rayaTitularPrestatges pull-right"></div>
                </h1>
            </div>
<div class="wrapper-prestatges rowPrestatges">

            <div class="jcarousel-wrapper-prestatges">
                <div class="jcarousel-prestatges">
                    <ul id="ulPrestatges">
                    <c:forEach var="articleMarkupPrestatges" items="${articlesMarkupPrestatges}" varStatus="loop">
                        <li>${articleMarkupPrestatges}</li>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges left carousel-control pruebaAddClass"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next-prestatges right carousel-control"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>

<!--                <p class="jcarousel-pagination-prestatges"></p> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {

            $(function() {
                var jcarousel = $('.jcarousel-prestatges');
                var perPageValue = $(this);

                jcarousel
                    .on('jcarousel:reload jcarousel:create', function () {

                        var carouselPrestatges = $(this);
                        var widthWindow = window.innerWidth;

                        carouselPrestatges.css('width', '100%');
                        var widthCarouselPrestatges = carouselPrestatges.innerWidth();
                        carouselPrestatges.css('width', widthCarouselPrestatges + 'px');

                        if (widthWindow >= 1200) {
                            widthCarouselPrestatges = widthCarouselPrestatges / 7;
                            perPageValue = 7;
                        } else if (widthWindow >= 992) {
                            widthCarouselPrestatges = widthCarouselPrestatges / 5;
                            perPageValue = 5;
                        } else if (widthWindow >= 768) {
                            widthCarouselPrestatges = widthCarouselPrestatges / 3;
                            perPageValue = 3;
                        } else {
                            perPageValue = 1;
                        }

                        carouselPrestatges.jcarousel('items').css('width', Math.ceil(widthCarouselPrestatges) + 'px');
                        $('#ulPrestatges').css('width', '20000em');                     

                    $('.jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges')
                        .jcarouselControl({
                            target: '-=' + perPageValue
                        });

                    $('.jcarousel-control-next-prestatges')
                        .jcarouselControl({
                            target: '+=' + perPageValue
                        });

                    $('.jcarousel-pagination-prestatges')
                        .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
                            $(this).addClass('active');
                        })
                        .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('active');
                        })
                        .on('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        })
                        .jcarouselPagination({
                            perPage: perPageValue,
                            item: function(page) {
                                return '<a href="#' + page + '">' + page + '</a>';
                            }
                        });

                    })
                    .jcarousel({
                        wrap: null,
                    });

            });
        })(jqCarrusel);
        var left = $('.jcarousel-prestatges ul').css('left');
        var posicion = "inicio"; // podria ser necesaria?
        $('.jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges')
        .click(function () {
            left = $('.jcarousel-prestatges ul').css('left');
            if (left == "0px" || left == "auto") {
                $('.jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges').addClass('pruebaAddClass');
            } else {
                $('.jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges').removeClass('pruebaAddClass');
                $('.jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges').addClass('aaa');
            };
        });
        $('.jcarousel-control-next-prestatges')
        .click(function () {
            left = $('.jcarousel-prestatges ul').css('left');
            if (left == "0px" || left == "auto") {
                $('.jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges').addClass('avanzaAddClass');
                $('.jcarousel-control-prev-prestatges').removeClass('pruebaAddClass');
            };
        });
        </script>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this could be considered a duplicate question (especially since OP for this question also had multiple carousels): [bootstrap carousel hide controls on first and last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467666/bootstrap-carousel-hide-controls-on-first-and-last)

However, with a little bit of searching on both SO and the internet, I was able to find an outstanding [blog post](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/06/05/how-to-hide-carousel-controls-on-first-and-last-items-in-bootstrap-3/) (also referenced by [Fred K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252920/fred-k)) that does a great job explaining this.