# Stop carousel from looping

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap v5.2 carousel but it should not loop after the last page.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">

        <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-interval="false">

          <div class="">

            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>

          </div>

          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>First slide label</h5>
                  <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                  <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                  <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="">Previous</span>
          </button>
            <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">

            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="">Next</span>
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Twitter Bootstrap Carousel at the end of it's slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441474/stop-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-at-the-end-of-its-slides)

Comment: No. This is bootstrap 5.2. please help. Let me revise the question

Comment: Hello dear, add bootstrap5 tag, to your question!

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to provide a data attribute to your carousel. According to Bootstrap 5 documentation, setting `wrap` to `false` will achieve the goal.

```
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" 
    class="carousel slide" 
    data-bs-ride="false" 
    data-bs-wrap="false"> // this is what you need to add.
```

Reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#options

Comment: This doesnt work!